# Low-hanging projector for high ceiling

Tags: projector

For our home cinema, I have selected an [Epson EH-TW710](https://www.epson.eu/en_EU/products/projectors/home-cinema/eh-tw710/p/29756) projector that I plan to mount to the ceiling.

We have quite a high ceiling (2.9 m). The simulation I did with the [Epson website](https://epson.com/support/projection-distance-calculators) shows that with a screen placed 0.9m (from the floor to its bottom edge), the projector has to hang at ~1.3 m from the ceiling. If I raise the screen to 1.2 m above the ground, the projector can be 1 m below the ceiling. Fortunately, this projector supports lens shift up to -60% vertically, so I can move it closer to the ceiling: 0.7 m or even 0.4 m.

Here's a side view of the latter solution.

[image]

I don't like the solution with a large projector mount sticking out of the ceiling. What else can I do?

Comment: Can you move it back to the rear wall and mount on a shelf?

Comment: @matt Not in our case. The room is bigger (7m depth, I pictured only the "cinema corner") and the projector working range is 2,7-4,3m (for 2m wide screen). It could be some kind of a table/mobile shelf, though but that means setting up and calibrating every time we want to watch something. Alternatively, use an adjustable mount ($$$) for the ceiling...

Comment: If I understand correctly I need also a mount allowing me to change the projector angle. The tilt-shift of the lens is not to change the angle but to compensate for it.

Comment: what else can you do?    lower the ceiling, raise the screen, raise the floor, get a different projector, back projection...

Comment: ... Flatscreen rather than projector, see if long-throw lenses can be swapped in, put projector on coffee table, $pring for one of the la$er-ba$ed projector$ that can sit flat again$t  the wall they are projecting upon...

Comment: Get a motorized drop down mount.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because doesn't seem to fall within the scope of [diy.se] defined in the help.

Comment: Put it on a stand on the floor (with cupholders on top)? Mount it vertically above the ceiling with an angled mirror below it and set the projector to mirror (Rear projection screen mode?) the image? (Confirm that the cooling system will work in this orientation.)

Comment: You selected an inappropriate projector for your purposes or preferences. Easiest solution is to select one that actually fits your purposes or preferences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

- deal with it
- use a different projector or lens that allows you to put the projector on the rear wall
- use a drop-down projector mount, so you only see the mount when the lights are off
- use a display instead of a projection screen

keep in mind that you should never plan to use the extreme ends of your lens shift, both because of distortion and to have some wiggle room

Answer (score 1):

See if you can mount the projector pointing downwards at a slight angle.  This will allow it to point further down the wall, while still being mounted higher up.

But it will change the distortion of the picture, and you need to make sure that won't go outside the range that the projector can correct for.

Comment: Right, I could point downwards + correct with keystone correction + shift down even more with lens shift. All those are available in this projector + for pointing downwards I need the right mount. Thanks.